# Dynamically load javascript with global var

Tags: jquery, include, blockly

My project requires to :

- set values to global variable
- then load external JavaScript which uses this global variable
- then change variable and load again same javascript while the external javascript looks as (using Google Blockly):

  ```
  Blockly.Blocks[block_name+'_autogetter_state'] = {
      init: function() {
          this.setName(block_name);
      }
  };
  ```

and the global variable is **block_name** it seems that since i pass there variable it is only passed variable and not its value. So if I call the javascript twice and load it to some HTML, it seems that both blocks looks same.

probably the way I load the javascript is not important, I tried:

```
$('#htmlElement').append('<script src="' + jsURL + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
```

and also via AJAX and then load it to HTML between `<script>` tag.

so the imported code then looks like:

```
<script> var block_name='';</script>
<div id="htmlElement">
      <script>
           block_name='A';
           Blockly.Blocks[block_name+'_autogetter_state'] = {
               init: function() {
                   this.setName(block_name);
               }
           };
           block_name='B';
           Blockly.Blocks[block_name+'_autogetter_state'] = {
               init: function() {
                   this.setName(block_name);
               }
           };
       </script>
</div>
```

while first block is with name = B and second also, while first should be A and second B. Fun part comes when you use the block with name A it works, so the system knows block with name A, but displays with name B.

It is also possible that while they are loaded asynchronously, the global variable is half filled with A and becomes B while the functions behind method .Blocks takes over and registers it as B...

But by now I want to make sure that there is no problem with passing global variable to imported javascript as I do... And am open to any suggestions since my creativity is pretty gone already with this case...

Answer (score 1):

Could use an array and a loop to avoid code duplication and improve scalability:

```
var block_names = ['A', 'B'];
block_names.forEach(function(block) {
  Blockly.Blocks[block + '_autogetter_state'] = {
     init: function() {
       this.setName(block);
     }
  };    
});
```

*//edit: block_name to block in setName fn.*

Comment: Hello charlietfl, after several trials I made it work and yours solution was correct, could you please provide some further explanation why was happening what was happening? As I can see it it was all fault of using global variables while in yours solution is used private variable of forEach function so the Blocks functions doesnt goes through same variables since they are not global. Is it right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Also sorry, previous comment was half done, and I passed it,then deleted it while in further testing I saw its working, so you saw probably fragment of old comment